# my nokia lumia 520 battery is draining fast after i updated to windows 8.1.any solutions?

Tags: battery

My nokia lumia 520 battery is draining fast after i updated to windows 8.1.any solutions?
It drains about 5 percentage each 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a hard reset fixes most of the problems that occur after an update to Windows Phone 8.1.
Also check the battery saver to see what might drain your battery.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few basic reasons for more battery consumption:

1. When Location services ON (GPS)
2. Using 3G/4G Data connection (Downloading / uploading). If the 3G signal is poor, or coverage fluctuates, 3G will use much more power while actively transferring data.
3. Applications running in background (Background Tasks)
4. Playing Games.
5. Display Screen Brightness and Screen Timeout.
6. Keeping phone in hot place.

Check the above in your case and turn off unwanted stuff.

If the problem still persists, then go to Nokia Care.

Answer (score 0):

Try hard resetting first. If it's unusual, hopefully that will work.

If it do not works the same, try uninstalling the apps that works in background, or limiting them to not to work in background.

You can also Disable Hey Cortana feature, turn off data setting when not in use, turn off WiFi and location service, Turn ON battery saver, disable some apps to work in background that may help.

Source: [How to improve battery life in Windows Phone 10](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2016/01/how-to-improve-battery-life-in-Windows-Phone-10.html)